# Syntax Error, malformed JSON HTTP POST

Tags: php, android, json, webservice, gson

Tengo un objeto que he pasado a JSON mediante Gson. El caso es que en mi WebService php he puesto una función que analiza si el JSON es correcto y me está dando el error:

> Syntax error, malformed JSON

Este es mi funcion en php que comprueba el JSON:

```
function json_validate($string)
{
    // decode the JSON data
    $result = json_decode($string);

    // switch and check possible JSON errors
    switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            $error = ''; // JSON is valid // No error has occurred
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            $error = 'The maximum stack depth has been exceeded.';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            $error = 'Invalid or malformed JSON.';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            $error = 'Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded.';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            $error = 'Syntax error, malformed JSON.';
            break;
        // PHP >= 5.3.3
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            $error = 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded.';
            break;
        // PHP >= 5.5.0
        case JSON_ERROR_RECURSION:
            $error = 'One or more recursive references in the value to be encoded.';
            break;
        // PHP >= 5.5.0
        case JSON_ERROR_INF_OR_NAN:
            $error = 'One or more NAN or INF values in the value to be encoded.';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_TYPE:
            $error = 'A value of a type that cannot be encoded was given.';
            break;
        default:
            $error = 'Unknown JSON error occured.';
            break;
    }

    if ($error !== '') {
        // throw the Exception or exit // or whatever :)
        exit($error);
    }

    // everything is OK
    return $result;
}
```

Así es como recojo y compruebo el JSON en el webservice php:

```
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $obj = json_decode($json);

    $output = json_validate($json);
    print_r($output);
```

y por ultimo cómo transformo el objeto a JSON y lo envío desde Android:

public void sendPost() {

```
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(myURL);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.setDoInput(true);

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    String JSON = gson.toJson(miPlan);


                    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(JSON, "UTF-8"));;

                    os.flush();
                    os.close();

                    Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
                    Log.i("MSG" , conn.getResponseMessage());

                    StringBuffer response = null;

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;
                    response = new StringBuffer();
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                    }
                    in.close();

Log.i("RESPUESTA" , response.toString().trim());

                    if(response.toString().trim().equals("1"))
                    {
                        exito=1;
                    }

                    conn.disconnect();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }
```

¿Alguien ve lo que está fallando? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución, por si a alguien le sirve la dejo

He sustituido este código:

```
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(JSON, "UTF-8"));;

os.flush();
os.close();
```

Por este:

```
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");

osw.write(JSON.toString());
osw.flush();
osw.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

El error que describes:

> Syntax Error, malformed JSON HTTP POST

Indica que el formato de la llamada a la API es incorrecto.

Al ver tu código, si realizas una petición POST debes enviar los parámetros y sus valores en el "body" y al parecer no realizas esto.

```
URL url = new URL(myURL);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String JSON = gson.toJson(miPlan);
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(JSON /*Parametros*/, "UTF-8"));;
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Debes definir los parámetros y sus valores contenidos en `JSON` a la conexión de esta forma mediante el método `write()`:

```
...
...
String JSON = gson.toJson(miPlan);
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(JSON.getBytes("UTF-8"));
os.flush();
os.close();
```